# Span Hover in IE

Tags: html, css

Hello pls could someone help... I've tried everything to get this to work in IE (typical) - I need to get a span to hover with a background image, with multiple background hover images also in the same div.  It's for a nav bar.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="menu2">
     <ul> 
    <li><a href="#"><span><img src="/images/Structure/home-active.png" /></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Directory</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Events</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Jobs</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Property</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>News</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Community</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Travel</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Advertise</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Login</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
/* Main Menu */
.menu2 {clear:both;position:relative;z-index:2;margin:0 auto;width:100%;height:41px;max-width:1280px;}
.menu2 ul.first {float:left;}
.menu2 li {float:left;height:41px;background:transparent url(/images/menu-icons/test/left.png) left top no-repeat;margin:0 5px;}
.menu2 li a {padding:0 4px;float:left;color:#222222;font-size:14px;line-height:40px;font-weight:bold;background:transparent url(/images/menu-icons/test/right.png) right top no-repeat;}
.menu2 li a span {height:41px;padding:0 8px;display:block;background:transparent url(/images/menu-icons/test/repeat.png) repeat-x;}

.menu2 li:hover {text-decoration:none;background:transparent url(/images/menu-icons/test/hov-left.png) left top no-repeat;}
.menu2 li a:hover {text-decoration:none;background:transparent url(/images/menu-icons/test/hov-right.png) right top no-repeat;}
.menu2 a:hover span {display:block;color:#fff;background:transparent url(/images/menu-icons/test/hov-repeat.png)repeat-x;}
```

As you can see the very last style in the CSS is where it's not working...

This is what's happening (view in ie obv.) http://www.dev.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/news.html

Any help would be amazing..

Comment: Not related to your question, you should also try images a little bit bigger and CSS Sprite technique to reduce HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears an issue with the selector `.menu2 a:hover span`. Try replacing that line with:

```
.menu2 li a:hover span {display:block;color:#fff;background:transparent url(/images/menu-icons/test/hov-repeat.png) repeat-x;}
```

Note the extra 'li'. It should overwrite the style defined by `.menu2 li a span ...`

Also, you may want to add a space between the ) and repeat-x.

Comment: Try the last line of the solution, plz.

Comment: Sorry, all I got is to replace: <code>.menu2 a:hover span {display:block;color:#fff;background:transparent url(/images/menu-icons/test/hov-repeat.png)repeat-x;}</code> with the line I have provided and add a space between the closing bracket and the repeat-x statement;

Comment: You'd have to trigger the hover on the li instead of the 'a'. So that line with the a:hover would start with .menu2 li:hover a span { instead.

Comment: No prob Sue. Please flag the answer as a 'solution' so that others don't try to answer. Thanks. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in IE8 and IE8 compatibility mode, and the other browsers too.

```
background:transparent url(http://www.dev.inside-guides.co.uk/images/menu-icons/test/hov-repeat.png) repeat-x;
```

Was just a lack of space before the *repeat-x*. I've used with .**menu2 span:hover** and **.menu2 a:hover span:hover** both worked, meaning that you don't need the a:hover.

Comment: Actually 2 more pairs of eyes... Dimitry's had the sollution. His line was already corrected with the space. I didn't look at his line just at your answer. Sorry Dimitry.